# $match stage in mongodb aggregation pipeline not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to find profit of each account using mongodb and node.js i wrote this code but the main problem is i $match stage of aggregation pipeline i want to filter document according to accountNum and also rate but in my query filtering according to account number not work it return an empty array when i comment the account number and only filter by rate and grouping according to account number it work but i want to only find the profit of one person not all and filter data in $match state according to rate and accountNum both.
my code that return null value(filtering according to rate and accountNum in $match. i have some data with that account number):

```
 const profit = await roznamcha.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            rate: { $ne: 0 },
            accountNum:{$eq:'$req.query.accountNum'}
        }
    },

    {
        $addFields: {
            resultMultiply: {
                $divide: [
                    { $multiply: ["$credit", { $subtract: [100, "$rate"] }] }, 100
                ]

            },
            resultMultiplyde: {
                $divide: [
                    { $multiply: ["$debit", { $subtract: [100, "$rate"] }] }, 100
                ]

            },


        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: 0,
            sumcredit: {
                $sum: '$resultMultiply'
            },
            sumdebit: {
                $sum: '$resultMultiplyde'
            }


        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            finalProfit: { $subtract: ["$sumcredit", "$sumdebit"] }
        }
    }

])
    res.status(201).json({
        status: 'success',

        data: {
            profit
        }
    })
})
```

the code that work and return a value (filter according to rate only in $match stage)

```
const profit = await roznamcha.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            rate: { $ne: 0 },
            
        }
    },

    {
        $addFields: {
            resultMultiply: {
                $divide: [
                    { $multiply: ["$credit", { $subtract: [100, "$rate"] }] }, 100
                ]

            },
            resultMultiplyde: {
                $divide: [
                    { $multiply: ["$debit", { $subtract: [100, "$rate"] }] }, 100
                ]

            },


        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$accountNum',
            sumcredit: {
                $sum: '$resultMultiply'
            },
            sumdebit: {
                $sum: '$resultMultiplyde'
            }


        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            finalProfit: { $subtract: ["$sumcredit", "$sumdebit"] }
        }
    }

])
res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',

    data: {
        profit
    }
})
```

})

Comment: remove the single quote and $ from your input `{$eq:req.query.accountNum}`

Comment: `'$req.query.accountNum'` - is this a field name in the MongoDB document? In case its an external variable you cannot use the `$` prefix and the _quotes_ around the variable name.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a JSON body representing the data you are trying to query.  I can't test this because I don't have any sample data.